# Can you whitelist certain words from being auto-corrected?

Tags: macos, ios, keyboard, text-input, autocorrect

I'm aware you can turn off autocorrect entirely. However I feel like **Rick & Morty** is popular enough to warrant its exclusion from being autocorrected to **Marty**.

Is there any way to override/prevent auto-correct for specific words?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Who are "Rick and Morty", anyway?

Comment: Why are autocorrect issues being deemed "off-topic" - it's part of the supplied OS no? And Rick and Morty is a Sci Fi cartoon...

Comment: The question as originally phrased was probably off-topic. However it reflected a valid use-case with a clear solution that could help many users. So I edited it to steer it back on topic.

Comment: I find autocorrect annoying and leave it off, but as many find it useful and I like your answers.

Comment: @SolarMike, John Mayer [said](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgJ3kSOHMiU&t=0m13s) it best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, you can tap the little **×** in the autocorrect bubble to block the autocorrect (or pick the left-most choice if using **Predictive**). Do this enough times and iOS will learn your typing habits and stop trying to correct that word.

For a more permanent solution, you can also add that word into your systemwide custom dictionary.

On iOS, open **Settings** → **Keyboard** → **Text Replacement** → **+**
Under **Phrase** enter `Morty`. Then either leave the **Shortcut** field blank, or enter `morty` in lowercase so the name gets capitalized automatically.

Note that these text replacements synchronize across your iOS and macOS devices over iCloud. However if you also want to add a word on macOS, it’s under **** → **System Preferences** → **Keyboard** → **Text**.

Comment: That works for now, but it'd be nice if it was native.

Comment: @uwnojpjm See my edit. I've added a more permanent solution.